# how to use double for statement creates a loop to sort Array to deal with the Array which has month and day?

Tags: javascript, arrays

how to deal with the Array below which has month and day using double if else condition cyclic based on month?

inputArray:

```
var arr = [
            {day: '02',ecount:22,month:"02"},
            {day: '03',ecount:23,month:"02"},
            {day: '01',ecount:21,month:"02"},
            {day: '02',ecount:12,month:"01"},
            {day: '01',ecount:11,month:"01"},
            {day: '03',ecount:13,month:"01"},
        ];
```

i want get data like 
outputArray:

```
 var newArray = [ [11,12,13],[21,22,23] ]
```

here is my code, but i failed!

```
function stringToNum(str) {
        str = (str.charAt(0) === '0')?parseInt(str.substr(1)):  parseInt(str);

        return str;
    };
    var monthDataArray = [];
    var dateArray = [];
    for(var i=1;i<=12;i++){
        for(var j=0;j<arr.length;j++){
            if(stringToNum(arr[j].month)===i){
                dateArray[stringToNum(arr[j].day)-1]=arr[j].ecount;
                monthDataArray[i-1] = dateArray;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Do you know beforehand how many months there will be and how many days each will have?

Comment: @Bergi i don't know. So I try to use the double for statement creates a loop to match

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could sort the data first and the iterate by checking the last element and the month of it. Then decide if a new array is necessary or just append the value to the last array.

```js
var array = [{ day: '03', ecount:23, month: "02" }, { day: '02', ecount:22, month: "02" }, { day: '01', ecount:21, month: "02"}, { day: '03', ecount:13, month: "01" }, { day: '02', ecount:12, month: "01" }, { day: '01', ecount:11, month: "01" }],
    result;
       
array.sort(function (a, b) { 
    return a.month - b.month || a.day - b.day;
});

result = array.reduce(function (r, a, i, aa) {
    if ((aa[i - 1] || {}).month === a.month) {
        r[r.length - 1].push(a.ecount);
    } else {
        r.push([a.ecount]);
    }
    return r;
}, []);

console.log(result);
```

With `for` statement.

```js
var array = [{ day: '03', ecount:23, month: "02" }, { day: '02', ecount:22, month: "02" }, { day: '01', ecount:21, month: "02"}, { day: '03', ecount:13, month: "01" }, { day: '02', ecount:12, month: "01" }, { day: '01', ecount:11, month: "01" }],
    result = [],
    i;
       
array.sort(function (a, b) { 
    return a.month - b.month || a.day - b.day;
});

for (i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    if ((array[i - 1] || {}).month === array[i].month) {
        result[result.length - 1].push(array[i].ecount);
    } else {
        result.push([array[i].ecount]);
    }
}

console.log(result);
```

Grouping count by month and day and filling missing values with zero.

```js
var array = [{ day: '03', ecount:23, month: "02" }, { day: '02', ecount:22, month: "02" }, { day: '11', ecount:21, month: "02"}, { day: '03', ecount:13, month: "01" }, { day: '02', ecount:12, month: "01" }, { day: '01', ecount:11, month: "01" }],
    count = Object.create(null),
    result;
       
array.forEach(function (a) {
    count[a.month] = count[a.month] || Array.apply(null, { length: 32 }).map(function () { return 0; });
    count[a.month][+a.day] += a.ecount;
});

result = Object.keys(count).sort(function (a, b) { return a - b; }).map(function (m) {
    return count[m].slice(1);
});

console.log(result);
console.log(count);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, I also want to learn how to use if...else to finish it

Comment: I want to use the for statement creates a loop with if...else to finish it

Comment: @CeleKing, please see edit. it uses the same structure as in `reduce`, but it does work on the result array directly and does not require a `return` statement.

Comment: sorry, I just thought it can't use sort to operate if the value of "day" in array isn't continuous. For examples if the array lack two days of ecount

Comment: if you do not have continuous days gicen, the array version does not work. you need to build an array first with all day and the render the count arrays. the actual data structure may not the best structure for it. it would be better to use a tree structure for collecting month and day counts and then render the result set out of the collected data.

Comment: I am trying my best to finish it, but it's a little hart for me. Could you teach me some codes for help ? Anyway thank you very much.